# Quartz Cron scheduler in Spring with jdbc store

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, cron, quartz-scheduler

I need to create Cron service in Spring, but I can not find enough info how to do it with jdbc store. I want Quartz to use my present connection to Datasource, my database is PostgreSql. I need to create use jdbc store, because task should be done even if server was down.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<bean id="scheduler-JDBC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">false</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cronScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" parent="scheduler-JDBC">
    <property name="startupDelay" value="10" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myTrigger" />                
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Download Quartz distribution from http://quartz-scheduler.org/ and you will find the database script for needed tables in docs/dbTables.